# Django setting are not configured error

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-settings

I'm trying to test models in my Django project, although I'm getting an error when I run my code. I'm using Python 2.7.
The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PopulateModels.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.db.models.query import Q
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.db.models.deletion import Collector
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.db.models import signals, sql
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.db.models.sql.subqueries import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/subqueries.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.db.models.sql.query import Query
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 22, in <module>
    from django.db.models.sql import aggregates as base_aggregates_module
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/aggregates.py", line 9, in <module>
    ordinal_aggregate_field = IntegerField()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 116, in __init__
    self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 47, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I'm not sure if it helps, but I'm trying to run a program to test my app's models. So the code I'm trying to run is in an App_Folder, and then the models are in: `App_Folder/indieapp-master/indie_app/product_extend/models.py`. I'm not sure what to do to fix this. Any guidance would be great! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can define this attribute in your models, if you want to control it in Python, since you didn't set it in your configs.

The example from the docs shows you how:

```
class TablespaceExample(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index=True, db_tablespace="indexes")
    data = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    edges = models.ManyToManyField(to="self", db_tablespace="indexes")

    class Meta:
        db_tablespace = "tables"
```

Comment: Sorry do you mean changing the 'db_tablespace="tables"' in the 'models.py'? I tried putting it in the 'models.py' file and I still got the same error. Is there something I could change in the '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py' file?